# GET data from URL to Webpage

Tags: javascript, php

I need help getting data from URL variables in PHP.

For example, if the URL is:

```
http://example.com/get.php?url=http://www.example.com/live.php?final=99999999999999999&go=2093
```

I want the value for the input field named `final` to be:

```
<input name="final" type="hidden" value="<?php echo("".$_GET['final']."");?>">
```

If this can be done with JavaScript, that works too.

Comment: Technically no, the random concatenated empty quotes are pointless, and it's not very safe at all, but it should work.

Comment: Stop to put negative on answers, I really guess you question is not clear at all ... ! From where are you getting the $_GET['final'] in your question ??

Comment: I have not downvoted anyone, but If question is not clear then no need to answer it.

Comment: In this case, give more details about the $_GET['final']. What are you expecting with the url given ?

Comment: @zeflex it is getting from url

Comment: @zeflex i want to get data from url parameter but it is not getting because its ?url=url

Comment: You should escape the live.php URL that's in the query paramaters, otherwise, retrieving it is a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$urlSplitted = explode('?final=', $_GET['url']);
$final = $urlSplitted[1];

<input name="final" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $final; ?>">
```

Try it ?

Comment: No. I replaced a '?' by a '&' before 'final=99999999999999999'

Comment: It shows value empty as - <input name="final" type="hidden" value="">

Comment: I missed the echo before $final, add it.

Comment: Welcome! Be more explicit if you need help next time, it will avoid headaches :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77148/discussion-between-zeflex-and-sukhchain-singh).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="final" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['final'] ?>" />
```

This will work but please don't take stuff directly from $_GET and put it on your page without validation. At the very least do this:

```
$final = isset($_GET['final']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['final']) : '';
//Replace the empty quotes above with whatever you want it to be set to
//if ?final= is not set in the URL
?>
<input name="final" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $final ?>" />
```

htmlspecialchars will escape any html elements from the URL to prevent people from using their own scripts etc.

See [here](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) fore more info.

Comment: It's working fine my end. You realise that your input is hidden, right? So make sure you are viewing source code to test it. I literally have only the above code on my page, and go to ?final=xyz - and it's working no problem, so there must be some additional code somewhere if yours is not working.

Comment: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: final in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\lp\get.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />

`<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php $final = htmlspecialchars($_GET['final']); ?>
<?php echo $final ?>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: This means you haven't actually set the URL as get.php?final=anything - You need to set it. Just put an if around the $final setting and you can capture whether or not it is set. I edited my answer to account for this.